# Symfony Session variable from php file GetuserID

Tags: php, symfony, session, twig

i'm trying to add arrowchat, an tchat box from arrowchat.com And these file is just using php without using twig in my website and i don't know how to do for integrate this file with my session variable from twig.

This is what i need to do for integrate these file:

First, open the arrowchat/includes/integration.php file. This file must be customized to fit your specific website.

get_user_id() Function

The first and most important function to setup is the get_user_id() function. This function will simply return the user's ID or NULL if no user is logged in. The two most common ways to setup this function are by cookie and session.

Using a Session example:

```
function get_user_id() 
{
    $userid = NULL;

    if (!empty($_SESSION['userid']))
    {
        $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
    }

    return $userid;
}
```

My problem is:
It's not working and i think it's because $_SESSION['userid'] doesn't exist.

How can i do for take the user id from my session without using twig?
I'm using FOSUserBundle for making the session when i connect to my website

Thanks all :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are into a controller you can do this with FOSUserBundle:

```
$user = $this->getUser();

if (null != $user) {
   $userid = $user->getId();
}
```

Comment: this not from controller, the code is from integration.php who don't use twig too

Comment: If you are using Symfony you pass into a controller, inside your controller you can set a variable and pass It into your file

Comment: i know but i'm using an tchat box from https://www.arrowchat.com/
And these file is just using php without using twig

Comment: specify It into the question please :)

Comment: "i'm trying to add arrowchat in my website but they use some php file and i don't know how to do for integrate this file with my session variable from twig."

Comment: Ok, link arrowchat to make understandable to user what is :) only that please